# How to connect lines in single feature in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I have a some tables in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I want to create view to publish it on Geoserver. But I have a problem with geometry. I have a geometry of segments of line. For example this segments from same line:

```
0xE610000001040C000000F01472A59E5A524032C7F2AE7AAA4E40AC1E300F995A52403C889D2974AA4E408C666
5FB905A5240213F1BB96EAA4E406A12BC218D5A5240B7F0BC546CAA4E404A404CC2855A5240ACAA97DF69AA4E40
4E2A1A6B7F5A5240D7A546E867AA4E402B85402E715A5240BAC0E5B166AA4E400EA0DFF76F5A52405AB8ACC266A
A4E402E3883BF5F5A5240D7A546E867AA4E403AE63C635F5A5240D7A546E867AA4E40043A9336555A5240D2393F
C571AA4E405CCCCF0D4D5A5240A75B76887FAA4E4001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002

0xE610000001040A000000F01472A59E5A524032C7F2AE7AAA4E4011C47938815A52401DE4F56052AA4E40145D1
77E705A52401364045438AA4E404B00FE29555A5240DE74CB0EF1A94E4059130B7C455A5240FED2A23EC9A94E40
C9B08A37325A52407444BE4BA9A94E402B323A20095A524049D576137CA94E408B1A4CC3F0595240342C465D6BA
94E40E0F3C308E1595240F487669E5CA94E40B169A510C8595240CBBA7F2C44A94E400100000001000000000100
0000FFFFFFFF0000000002
```

To select segments i use this query:

```
SELECT  

    Segment_ID = Segment_ID.Segment_ID,
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
    Road.Name as Road_Name,
    Road.Road_ID as Road_Id



FROM dbo.Road
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
```

Is it possible to join segments in one feature in single query?

**UPDATE**

I found function [STUnion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb933850.aspx) but don't know how to use it to join segments in single query.

**UPDATE2**

I think i gonna talk about tables structure. I have 3 tables:

Track

```
Segment_ID(character),
Track (geometry)
```

Segment_ID

```
Segment_ID(character),
Road_ID(character)
```

Road

```
Road_ID(character),
Road_Name(character)
```

And in query result i eant to get Road_Name and all segment connected in single feature for this Road.
But still cant write cant query(

**UPDATE3**

Solution in answer works but its take alot of time. I mean when i press execute query i get result within 2seconds but query still work about 5 minutes.
 Its possible to make it faster. Bercouse i create view from this query and add it to Geoserver but i cant get layer in Layers Preview becouse get Timeout error.

I see something interesting. In table Road i have 76 rows. When i press execute query i get 75 rows and after 5 minutes i get all 76 rows. So problem in last iteration. What can be wrong?

Comment: STUnion is definitely the way to go. How do you know which segments you want added together? Your query appears to only produce one geometry column.

Comment: @BenThul: I update question. Please look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STUnion is indeed your road (ha!) to salvation. STUnion is a method on the geometry and geography CLR types. You'd typically invoke it as `gInstance.STUnion(othergInstance)`. That said, assuming that your query above generates the appropriate geometry instances, this recursive CTE solution should work:

```
with by_segment as (
SELECT  
    Road.Road_Id,
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
    row_number() over (partition by Road.road_id order by Road.Segment_Id) as [rn],
    count(*) over (partition by Road.road_id) as [c]
FROM dbo.Road
LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
),
roads_by_segment as (
select 
   road_id,
   the_geom,
   [rn],
   [c]
from by_segment
where [rn] = 1

union all

select 
   [a].road_id,
   [a].the_geom.STUnion([b].the_geom),
   [b].[rn],
   [b].[c]
from by_segment as [a]
inner join roads_by_segment as [b]
   on [a].Road_ID = b.Road_ID
   and [a].[rn] = [b].[rn]+1
)

select * from roads_by_segment where [rn] = [c]
```

Comment: Sql-Server says that we have an error here `partition by road_id order by Segment_Id)` - error near key word `order` he says.

Comment: Ah... yes. I'd copied the over clause between the row_number and count. Obviously you don't need an order by for a count! I've edited it.

Comment: I get error in lines `partition by road_id order by Segment_Id` and ` partition by road_id` its says ` ambiguous column name`. What can i do whit it?

Comment: Code updated. It took me 30 seconds. You're much more likely to get help in the future if you say what you tried rather than just say "it didn't work".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for my bad question style.

Comment: It wasn't the bad question (which it wasn't), but rather the seeming lack of effort when presented with a 95% solution. You have to keep in mind that you have an accurate copy of your schema and I'm writing the query more or less with out that. In this case, it was literally a missing comma.