# How to accelerate SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im new with MS SQL-Server.  But already have a problem with it.
I have a query:

```
   with by_segment as (
    SELECT  
    Road.Road_ID,
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(Track.Track.STAsText(),4326) as the_geom,
    row_number() over (partition by road_id order by Segment_Id) as [rn],
    count(*) over (partition by road_id) as [c]
 FROM dbo.Road
 LEFT JOIN Segment_ID  ON Road.Road_ID = Segment_ID.Road_ID
 LEFT JOIN Track ON Segment_ID.Segment_ID = Track.Segment_ID
 ),
roads_by_segment as ( 
select 
  road_id,
  the_geom,
  [rn],
  [c]
from by_segment
where [rn] = 1

union all

select 
   [a].road_id,
   [a].the_geom.STUnion([b].the_geom),
   [b].[rn],
   [b].[c]
from by_segment as [a]
inner join roads_by_segment as [b]
 on [a].segment_id = b.[segment_id]
 and [a].[rn] = [b].[rn]+1 
)

select * from roads_by_segment where [rn] = [c]
```

Its works but its take alot of time. I mean when i press execute query i get result within 2seconds but query still work about 5 minutes.
I think its becouse too many selects in here.  There selects need for function `geometry1.STUnion(geometry2)`.
Its possible to make function from this monster query? And using function can make this query faster?

**UPDATE**

I want to create view to publish it on Geoserver. But I have a problem with geometry. I have a geometry of segments of line.

I think i gonna talk about tables structure. I have 3 tables:

Track

```
Segment_ID(character),
Track (geometry)
```

Segment_ID

```
Segment_ID(character),
Road_ID(character)
```

Road

```
Road_ID(character),
Road_Name(character)
```

And in query result i eant to get Road.Name, Road.Road_ID and all segment connected in single feature for this Road.

**UPDATE**

I see something interesting. In table Road i have 76 rows. When i press execute query i get 75 rows and after 5 minutes i get all 76 rows. So problem in last iteration. What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Execution plan http://sd.reborn.ru/download.php?fid=f52cb6c6146fdb993c1375f8b1da4787

Comment: Okay. This site isn't a "do my work for me" site. Specifically, you've taken the query that I wrote for you here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943346/how-to-connect-lines-in-single-feature-in-sql-server/14949585), presented it as your own, and are now asking people to tune that. What have you tried yourself? Only you have access to your actual data, so any efforts put in here are going to be mainly speculative. Have you looked at a query plan? What does that say? Tell us what you've tried and what has and hasn't worked and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to make function from this monster query?

```
--> Yes
```

And using function can make this query faster?

```
--> No
```

Sorry for this short answer. But without any backgroud information about business rules of your data model or technical details about plan it is not possible to give detailed improvement suggestions.

Comment: But what can i do to accelerate query>?

Comment: Sorry for bad question. I try update it within 2 minutes. Can you look at it?

Comment: Check the indexes on `road_id` column? If not exist, try to create one nonclustered (I suppose that you already have a clustered index on that table). Try to upload your execution plan, which graphically shows what SQL Server do when executing query? Any additional information will be great.

Comment: @veljasije: Im upload plan in question update. But dont know that do it right.

Comment: @KliverMax Ok, what I see from execution plan is that you have Clustered Index scan five times, and that is like scanning a table. Next, you have two operation which together take 70% of the entire batch, and those are points which can be improved. Thick lines with arrows means that from previous operation coming many rows. Try to comment part by part, to see any changes.

Comment: @veljasije: So i gonna use nonclastered index?

Comment: What if i create temporary table from `by_segment`?

Comment: @KliverMax No, you don't need to use temporary table, because SQL Server very well handle with Common Table Expressions or CTE. Try to execute same query, only without geometry column, and look is there any benefit. You need to do optimization step by step, commenting some parts of code and looking to execution plans and statistics, to see what is bottleneck. For start, leave only one SELECT part, lets say second.

Comment: @KliverMax Is there any result :)

Comment: @veljasije: Sorry but i find only solution with temp table. I create temp table from  by_segment. And after all works fine.

Comment: @KliverMax OK, keep in mind that temp tables are critical part of optimization, because SQL Server must optimize it in runtime.

Comment: @veljasije: Yeah i understand that temp tables not good. But i dont have enough time to find perfect solution. More sad that i can find any solution becouse dont know what i gonna find. Maybe you know nice book about SQL SERVER for newbie user?

Comment: @KliverMax For start, read this article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/. I hope I was helpful a little :)